# Submersion vs fiber bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submersions

If one starts with a fiber bundle $f: X \to Y$ so that fibers having trivial integral homology by using spectral sequence one can get the induced map $f_*: H_*(X;\mathbb{Z}) \to H_*(Y;\mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism.

My question is as follows:

Given a surjective submersion (I am not considering it to be proper) $f:X \to Y$ (connected smooth manifolds) such that all the fibers have trivial integral homology does this mean the induced map $f_*: H_*(X;\mathbb{Z}) \to H_*(Y;\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphism?

I will be grateful to see some counterexamples or proof.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No, that is not true.  This has come up in MO before.  I will include a link in the next comment.

Comment: @JasonStarr that will be really helpful..

Comment: Actually I was thinking of another example where all fibers are diffeomorphic, but the morphism is not a fiber bundle.  However, in the example that I know, the fibers have nontrivial integral cohomology (but the Kuenneth theorem does not hold, not even locally on the base).

Comment: It's true under the assumption that each fibre has trivial homotopy, in which case $f$ is a fibration and a homotopy equivalence (this is due to [G. Meigniez](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2002-354-09/S0002-9947-02-02972-0/)). This condition is sufficient but not necessary for $f$ to be a homology equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be true, and here is perhaps an over-sophisticated proof. By Poincare duality, homology identifies with compactly supported hypercohomology with coefficients in the Verdier dualizing sheaf $\omega_X$ (resp. $\omega_Y$), which is in the smooth case a shift of the orientation local system. The map in homology corresponds via this identification to the integration map $$H^*_c(X,\omega_X)\to H^*_c(Y,\omega_Y)$$, so we want this integration map to be an isomorphism.

This map is obtained from the counit $f_!f^!\omega_Y \to \omega_Y$ of the adjunction between derived categories $f_!\colon D(X)\leftrightarrows D(Y):f^!$ by taking sections with proper support, so its enough to show that this counit is an isomorphism in $D(Y)$. Here, $D(-)$ is the derived category of sheaves of abelian groups. Since $f$ is a submersion, we have a natural isomorphsm $f^!A\simeq f^*A\otimes \omega_f$ which shows that $f^!$ satisfies base-change along arbitrary smooth map $i\colon Z\to Y$.
Namely, for the projections $i'\colon X\times_Y Z\to Z$ and $f'\colon X\times_Y Z \to X$, we have $i^*f^! \simeq (f')^!(i')^*$.
In particular, taking $Z= \{y\}$ for $y\in Y$ and using also proper base-change, we see that the stalk of the map $f_!f^!\omega_Y\to \omega_Y$ at $y\in Y$ is the (derived) tensor product of the integration map $\int_{X_y}\colon C^*_c(X_y;\omega_{X_y})\to \mathbb{Z}$ for the fiber $X_y$ of $f$ over $Y$ with the identity map of the stalk $(\omega_Y)_y$. Finally, the assumption that all the fibers of $f$ are acyclic implies that the integration map $C^*_c(X_y;\omega_{X_y})\to \mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism in $D(Ab)$, by Poincare duality for the acyclic smooth manifold $X_y$.